# How to hide the only the title bar and not the soft keys in j2ME

Tags: java, java-me, canvas, midlet

How can I hide the title bar (and also the midlet icon) and not the softkeys in j2me midlets?
I am creating a midlet which make use of a canvas.the full screen mode hides both titles and soft keys. any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is impossible.

But you may *draw* your own softkeys: just leave some place at the bottom of the screen and draw, for example, two rectangles and two lines of text

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](http://java.sun.com/javame/reference/apis/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/Canvas.html#setFullScreenMode%28boolean%29) link. Note that this doesnt work on ALL J2ME handsets, Some Nokia ones have their own APIs for this.

Comment: setFullScreenMode(true) hides both the title bar and the soft key command actions.this is not what i need. I need to hide only the title bar and not the soft keys (commands). thanks

Comment: In this case you can use setFullScreenMode(true) and draw your own custom softkeys as BlaXpirit below says? That is not too hard to do.